# even the json is correct json parse not working in java script?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var data={
  "apple_scab": {
    "sym": "Dark velvet covering on leaves, Velvety olive-green to black spots on leaves",
    "cause": "Venturia inaequalis",
    "nc_c": "Use resistant varieties: Prima, Priscilla, Sir Prize, Jonafree, Red free, Dayton, Pristine, Goldrush, Enterprise or Liberty.",
    "c_c": "Use fungicide such as Captan."
  }}
```

The above JSON is parsed successfully by most of the online parsers

also, I can directly put this in js console in browser and I am able to read from the console.

If I assign to a variable when using json.parse() with variable giving an error:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

*VM568:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6*
```

Comment: becuase it is an object

Comment: your JSON looks like already parsed.

Comment: JSON is a string. `data` is an object. Parse expects a string. QED

Comment: That is JS, not JSON.  `the above json is parsed successfully by most of the online parsers`  This seems doubtful.

Comment: i have tried it is not working help me out

Comment: "i have tried it is not working help me out " It is already an object. You can not parse an object.... You are doing: JSON.parse("[object Object]") because object.toString returns "[object Object]"

Comment: epascarello - got it

Comment: This does not deserve so many downvotes! it's a good question that contains the entire problem, and all relevant error messages.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse` accepts a string, which is parsed and then returns an object full of the parsed data.  But you are passing it an object. `data` is already parsed, so you don't need `JSON.parse` here at all.

You are getting this error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` because of some weird quirks of javascript. Basically, it's trying to coerce the object into a string so that it can be parsed. And objects get coerced to string as simply `[object Object]`. So you are actually running

```
JSON.parse('[object Object]')
```

This is invalid json, and the error tells you the first character of the string that is invalid.

---

But in your case, you can simply use `data` without parsing.

```
var data={
  "apple_scab": {
    "sym": "Dark velvet covering on leaves, Velvety olive-green to black spots on leaves",
    "cause": "Venturia inaequalis",
    "nc_c": "Use resistant varieties: Prima, Priscilla, Sir Prize, Jonafree, Red free, Dayton, Pristine, Goldrush, Enterprise or Liberty.",
    "c_c": "Use fungicide such as Captan."
  }
}

console.log(data.apple_scab.cause) //-> Venturia inaequalis
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I gather, you are trying to parse an object that is already an object.

```
let someObject = { hello: "world" };
JSON.parse(someObject);
```

This will fail because `JSON.parse()` can not parse an object.

In order for that to succeed, it must a string.

```
let someJsonString = '{ "hello": "world" }';
let myObject = JSON.parse(someJsonString);
console.log(myObject);
```

This will succeed and parse the object.